# Could not connect to remote database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, connection

I have added the given below lines to config.inc.php file in the s `C:/xampp/phpmyadmin` folder and added the lines below

```
$i++;$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '172.16.10.100';$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

I have encountered the following error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> Cannot connect: invalid settings.   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the
>   MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check
>   the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure
>   that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of
>   the MySQL server.

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: This is unbelievable. What part of 'you should check the host, username, and password' don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

As in the documentation, it seems likely that the hostname, username or password in your string are incorrect.

Do you know that they are correct? MySQL can have host-specific passwords, so connecting from one server may require a different password to connecting from another.